# Unable to Install TesttNG plugin in Eclipse inside Virtual Desktop

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am trying to install TestNG plugin in eclipse 4.8.0 (Photon). I am doing this inside a VDI running Windows 7. I am trying to work with the URL:http://beust.com/eclipse

The eclipse progress bar shows Fetching Children forever and throws the error:

Polling news feeds: Unable to connect to repository :http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You mixed two issues. The _"Polling news feeds"_ is due to your outdated Eclipse version and unrelated here. The _"Unable to connect to repository"_ seems to be an issue of the very slow beust.com web server. Does using the URL `http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/` instead fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks @howlger I tried with that URL. But the issue still persists

Comment: Make sure _Contact all update sites during install to find required software_ is disabled. Can you access with a web browser http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/ from inside the Windows 7?

Comment: To disable news, open Preferences, then expand General, click on "news" and uncheck the options there.